# matlab 3D matrix creation query

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a 3D matrix in MATLAB. I have followed this [example](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html). My code is as such:

```
A1=zeros(50,2,10);
A1 = [1 2; 2 3; 3 11; 11 12; 11 9; 9 10; 9 7; 7 8; 7 5; 5 6; 5 4; 4 3];

A1(:,:,2) = [1 3; 3 2; 3 4; 3 5; 5 6; 6 7; 6 8; 6 9; 9 10; 10 11; 11 12; 12 13; 11 17; 17 16; 16 14; 14 15; 14 12; 16 18; 18 27; 18 19; 19 20; 20 21; 27 21; 27 26; 21 22; 26 25; 25 24; 24 22; 22 23]
```

The error I am getting is: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

 Where am I going wrong can someone tell me?

Comment: Could you explain the expected output? You are not assigning enough elements for a [50 2 10] matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do with `A1(:,:,2)` is that you want to insert a 50x2 matrix to the second position of a 50x2x10 hypermatrix. But the matrix of the right hand side has not not enough rows for it (29, instead of 50).

Comment: I didn't notice the `A1 = [1 2; 2 3; 3 11; 11 12; 11 9; 9 10; 9 7; 7 8; 7 5; 5 6; 5 4; 4 3];` assignment. However, you are not correct either, because that is a `12x2` matrix, not a `2x12`.

Comment: yes, not enough rows, i know, i want to fill the rest with zeros. 29 rows should be filled with my given data and the rest should be filled with zeros

Comment: The problem is that if I see well you want to create a `50x2x10` matrix, whose `(:,:,2)` elements should be that `29x2 matrix` (and the rest filled with zeros). If this is the problem, then a possible solution is:
`A1=zeros(50,2,10);
A1(1:29,:,2) = [1 3; 3 2; 3 4; 3 5; 5 6; 6 7; 6 8; 6 9; 9 10; 10 11; 11 12; 12 13; 11 17; 17 16; 16 14; 14 15; 14 12; 16 18; 18 27; 18 19; 19 20; 20 21; 27 21; 27 26; 21 22; 26 25; 25 24; 24 22; 22 23]`
What still remains unclear: what do you want to do with matrix `A1 = [1 2; 2 3; 3 11; 11 12; 11 9; 9 10; 9 7; 7 8; 7 5; 5 6; 5 4; 4 3]` in your second statement?

Comment: in second statement again fill up a 16*2 matrix in position 2, in this way

Comment: matrix in 1st position, another matrix of diff size in location 2 another in location 3

Comment: each position A(:,:,x) will have different sized matrix

Comment: You just have to know how many rows (let's denote it by `N`) you want to fill up at which position (denoted by `x`) and just use what I wrote:
`A1=zeros(50,2,10); A1(1:N,:,x) = [....];`.

Comment: N i know.. N is known to me

Comment: That's why you just replace N with the value you know.